# Create a simple TWO dimensional array in JavaScript. I am not just trying to append value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var a = ["1", "2"];
var b = ["a", "b"];
var c = [];
```

//Can someone suggest how do i push a and b into c such that c is a 2-dimensional array? (By using JavaScript)

//c should look like [["1","2"],["a","b"]]

Comment: `c.push(a, b)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) **Extremely** basic questions are best resolved with research and tutorials, not questions on Stack Overflow. Prior to asking a question on SO, you're expected to do thorough research.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a very basic question, the answer is:

```
var a = ["1", "2"];
var b = ["a", "b"];
var c = []; // you could have written c = [a, b];

c.push(a, b);
```

Comment: If i were to do that, c would result in [1,2,a,b] but I want c to be a two-dimensional array. It should be [[1,2],["a","b"]]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Just use push function and pass the array as an argument.
c.push(a);
c.push(b);
or push them together like: `c.push(a,b);`

Comment: If i were to do that, c would result in [1,2,a,b] but I want c to be a two-dimensional array. It should be [[1,2],["a","b"]]

Comment: No, you will get a two-dimensional array. push a and b into c and then console.log the c. You will see that c contains two arrays.